# how to use long options in c?

Tags: c, getopt, getopt-long

how to use long options via getopt_long:
for example like this:

```
--wide-option
```

I have `--wide` and `-w`.
And on -`-wide-option` it gives the following error:

> "unrecognized option"

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct option opts[] =
    {
        {"wide", 1, 0, 'w'},
        {
            0, 0, 0, 0
        }
    };
    int option_val = 0;
    int counter = 10;
    int opindex = 0;
    while ((option_val = getopt_long(argc, argv, "w:", opts, &opindex)) != -1)
    {
        switch (option_val)
        {
        case 'w':
            if (optarg != NULL)
                counter = atoi(optarg);
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                printf("Hello world\n");
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whar is your exact command line?

Comment: You have an option `--wide`; you do not have an option `--wide-option`. If I compile your code to `optiontest`, I can run `./optiontest --wide foo` without any errors.

Comment: cat -b filename(--number-nonblank). the above code is a test case

Comment: Sooo add `{"wide-option", 1, 0, ...},` if you want to have `--wide-option`.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `cat` source code ([here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cat.c)), you can see that `--number` and `--number-nonblank` are **two different options** (`-b` and `-n`). (near line 555).

If you want to do the same, you can that way:

```c
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct option opts[] =
    {
        {"wide", 1, 0, 'w'},
        {"wide-option", 0, 0, 'o'}, /* declare long opt here */
        {
            0, 0, 0, 0
        }
    };
    int option_val = 0;
    int counter = 10;
    int opindex = 0;
    while ((option_val = getopt_long(argc, argv, "w:o", opts, &opindex)) != -1) /* the case here (I arbitrary choose 'o') */
    {
        switch (option_val)
        {
        case 'w':
            if (optarg != NULL)
                counter = atoi(optarg);
            printf("option --wide %d found!\n", counter);
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                printf("Hello world\n");
            break;
         case 'o': /* and take the case into account */
                printf("option --wide-option found!\n");
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in that case i want to implement  "--number-nonblank".
в этом случае я хочу реализовать опцию -b и --number-nonblank

Comment: @Kuttubek Your questions are not clear, it's kinda hard to understand what exactly you want to achieve. If you want to implement as per your last comment, then add this into option struct: `{"number-nonblank", no_argument, NULL, 'b'},`, then program will accept `--number-nonblank` (and `-b`, which will be a short alternative for `--number-nonblank`, but will give the same result).

Comment: why the stddef.h library was included?